# Salvar $_POST com var_export depois gerar Variável novamente

Tags: php, post

Eu precisei gerar alguns dados pegando o conteúdo de um $_POST e salvando em um arquivo para processá-lo posteriormente.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$dados = $_POST;
$dados = var_export($dados, true);
$handle = fopen('posttemp.txt', 'a');
fwrite($handle, $dados);
fclose($handle);
```

Até aqui esta tudo bem, se abro o arquivo **posttemp.txt** este é o seu conteúdo.

```
array (
  'id' => '1832007',
  'post' => 
  array (
    'codigo' => '39063',
    'autor' => 'Christiano',
  ),
  'conteudo' => 
  array (
    'id' => '2526167',
    'dataInicio' => '2017-08-03 21:30:43',
    'dataFinalizada' => '2017-08-03 21:30:47',
    'status' => 'Publicado',
  ),
  'autor' => 
  array (
    'codigo' => '37276',
    'email' => 'seu@email.com',
    'nome' => '1 Lift Gold',
    'quantidade' => '1',
  )
)
```

Agora preciso pegar o conteúdo que foi salvo em **posttemp.txt** e transformar novamente em uma variável para que possa enviar novamente via POST.

Comment: Por quê não usa o `serialize` e `unserialize`?

Answer (score 1):

O `var_export` não tem um caminho reverso, o intuito dele é criar um *array* válido para o PHP, por exemplo se você deseja editar arquivos `.php` de configurações dinamicamente.

Um exemplo bem simplório seria isto:

Salva:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
);

$str = var_export($arr, true);
$str = '<?php' . PHP_EOL . 'return ' . $str . ';';

file_put_contents('config.php', $str);
```

Vai gerar o seguinte conteudo:

> ```
>  <?php
>  return array (
>    'a' => 1,
>    'b' => 2,
>    'c' => 3,
>  );
> ```

Usa os dados posteriormente:

```
<?php

$arr = include 'config.php'; //O return em includes retorna o valor

print_r($arr);
```

Isto pode ser um exemplo de uso que você deseja, pois o `config.php` irá carregar os dados na várivel `$arr` pelo `include`.

No entanto se deseja mesmo usar um arquivo `.txt` e se os dados **não são sensíveis** (como senhas ou códigos secretos), você pode usar funções como `serialize` e `unserialize`, por exemplo:

**gravar.php**

```
file_put_contents('posttemp.txt', serialize($_POST));
```

**ler.php**

```
$dados = file_get_contents('posttemp.txt'); // Lê o arquivo

$post_recuperado = unserialize($dados); //recria os valores

var_dump($post_recuperado); //Exibe com var_dump
```

> **Nota:**
>
> - `file_get_contents` lê o conteúdo do arquivo
> - `file_put_contents` grava o conteúdo no arquivo

Comment: Não seria melhor usar `json_decode` e `json_encode`? Segundo a própria documentação do `unserialize`: "Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless of the options value of allowed_classes.".